# how to use custom field default value on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-fields

i have a custom field in wordpress named cuisine
its a dropdown with the values of:
-asian
-african
-mexican
-american
-etc etc

whenever i add a post i can choose what type of cuisine it is.

now i have a custom page where all cuisine type should be there.
i want it dynamic which means it get its value from the custom field values
therefore i should be having this
-asian
-african
-mexican
-american
-etc etc
as my page contents.

problem:
how can i get this advance custom fields field? i mean the select field itself named cuisine
tried googling but always got different answer

*note: i am using 'Advanced Custom Fields 4.1.5.1' and 'WordPress v3.5.2'

Answer (score 1):

thanks anyway.. solved it already

```
get_field_object($field_key);
```

is the answer.
hope it helps someone who will encounter this kind of question in the near future